# Network Issue after flashing Cosmic ROM at Galaxy S Duos

Tags: custom-roms, kernel, samsung-galaxy-s-duos, dual-sim

I am a Galaxy S DUOS S7562 user and I have flashed Cosmic ROM v2.5 to my phone. However, I face some connectivity problems. My phone is dual sim but now it forever activates and deactivates both sims and it has started getting on my nerves! Besides, I cannot make calls. What's going on? My [dmesg output](http://pastebin.com/xdMXtayh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have the required baseband and did you use CWM recovery to install the zip file?
If yes, flash the Stock ROM again and root the phone, intall CWM and install v2 zip file first and then v2.5. 
I have been using Cosmic ROM v2.5 from the past one month and don't have any issues. 
You seem to be having issues only because of some goof up during installation. 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2503230 
He has given the .bin file for the supported baseband. Flash it via odin.